# Memory allocation error for multiple files “terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std :: bad_alloc' what (): std :: bad_alloc” [C ++]

Tags: c++, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation, memory-limit, multiple-file-upload

I am using a classifier algorithm for a digital voice signal processing project. This algorithm was developed to receive all the audio signals in a single vector to do the processing, but I'm having problems, because the number of files I'm working on is very large and is generating the error "terminate called after throwing an instance of ' std :: bad_alloc 'what (): std :: bad_alloc ". I would like to know if it is possible to make any changes to the code that reads the files and stores them in the vector more efficiently, without exceeding the available memory space.

Code for reading the files:

```
string filename;
    filename="C:\\Users\\marcu\\Desktop\\TCC\\Arquivos_10780\\Arquivos_DFT_TXT_512\\PA_D_00";

    std::vector<double> c;

    for(int j=1; j<=5400; j++)
    {
        stringstream ss;
        ss << filename << setw(5) << setfill('0') << j << "_bonafide_DFT.txt";

        std::ifstream f;
        f.open(ss.str().c_str());

        if (f.is_open())
        {
            double num;

            while (f >> num)
                c.push_back(num);

            f.close();
        }
        else
        {
            f.close();
            continue;
        }
    }

    for(int j=5401; j<=29700; j++)
    {
        stringstream ss;
        ss << filename << setw(5) << setfill('0') << j << "_spoof_DFT.txt";

        std::ifstream f;
        f.open(ss.str().c_str());

        if (f.is_open())
        {
            double num;

            while (f >> num)
                c.push_back(num);

            f.close();
        }
        else
        {
            f.close();
            continue;
        }
    }
```

Full code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<iomanip>
#include<sstream>

using namespace std;

double mean_similarities(double**,int,int);//vectors, number of vectors, their dimension

int main()
{
    const int number_of_classes=2;
    int number_of_feature_vectors_in_class[number_of_classes];
    number_of_feature_vectors_in_class[0]=2700;
    number_of_feature_vectors_in_class[1]=8080;
    const int dimension_of_each_feature_vector=512;

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/*
Example: 3 classes and 4 vectors of dimension 2 in each class
{{0.90,0.12},{0.88,0.14},{0.88,0.13},{0.89,0.11}}   //0.88---0.90 ; 0.11---0.14
{{0.55,0.53},{0.53,0.55},{0.54,0.54},{0.56,0.54}}   //0.53---0.56 ; 0.53---0.55
{{0.10,0.88},{0.11,0.86},{0.12,0.87},{0.11,0.88}}   //0.10---0.12 ; 0.86---0.88  

double c[]={ 
0.90,0.12,0.88,0.14,0.88,0.13,0.89,0.11,
0.55,0.53,0.53,0.55,0.54,0.54,0.56,0.54,
0.10,0.88,0.11,0.86,0.12,0.87,0.11,0.88
//all vectors in class C_1, followed by all vectors in C_2, ...., followed by all in C_n
            };
*/
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    string filename;
    filename="C:\\Users\\marcu\\Desktop\\TCC\\Arquivos_10780\\Arquivos_DFT_TXT_512\\PA_D_00";

    std::vector<double> c;

    for(int j=1; j<=5400; j++)
    {
        stringstream ss;
        ss << filename << setw(5) << setfill('0') << j << "_bonafide_DFT.txt";

        std::ifstream f;
        f.open(ss.str().c_str());

        if (f.is_open())
        {
            double num;

            while (f >> num)
                c.push_back(num);

            f.close();
        }
        else
        {
            f.close();
            continue;
        }
    }

    for(int j=5401; j<=29700; j++)
    {
        stringstream ss;
        ss << filename << setw(5) << setfill('0') << j << "_spoof_DFT.txt";

        std::ifstream f;
        f.open(ss.str().c_str());

        if (f.is_open())
        {
            double num;

            while (f >> num)
                c.push_back(num);

            f.close();
        }
        else
        {
            f.close();
            continue;
        }
    }

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//edit whatever you need, according to the feature vectors of your problem, ABOVE this line.
//Do NOT change anything BELOW this line !!!!!
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    double*** C=new double**[number_of_classes];
    for(int i=0; i<number_of_classes; i++)
        C[i]=new double*[number_of_feature_vectors_in_class[i]];
    for(int i=0; i<number_of_classes; i++)
        for(int j=0; j<number_of_feature_vectors_in_class[i]; j++)
            C[i][j]=new double[dimension_of_each_feature_vector];
    int l=0;
    for(int i=0; i<number_of_classes; i++)
        for(int j=0; j<number_of_feature_vectors_in_class[i]; j++)
            for(int k=0; k<dimension_of_each_feature_vector; k++)
            {
                C[i][j][k]=c[l];
                l++;
            }

//Debug info only
//for(int i=0;i<number_of_classes;i++)
//  for(int j=0;j<number_of_feature_vectors_in_class[i];j++)
//      for(int k=0;k<dimension_of_each_feature_vector;k++)
//          printf("\nclass %d vector %d element %d is %.3f",i,j,k,C[i][j][k]);
//getchar();
    double Y[number_of_classes];
    for(int i=0; i<number_of_classes; i++)
        Y[i]=mean_similarities(C[i],number_of_feature_vectors_in_class[i],dimension_of_each_feature_vector);
    double alpha=Y[0];
    for(int i=1; i<number_of_classes; i++)
        if(Y[i]<alpha)
            alpha=Y[i];
    printf("\nALPHA: %.3f",alpha);
    double** smallest_range_vector_for_class=new double*[number_of_classes];
    for(int i=0; i<number_of_classes; i++)
        smallest_range_vector_for_class[i]=new double[dimension_of_each_feature_vector];
    for(int i=0; i<number_of_classes; i++)
        for(int k=0; k<dimension_of_each_feature_vector; k++)
            smallest_range_vector_for_class[i][k]=C[i][0][k];
    for(int i=0; i<number_of_classes; i++)
        for(int j=1; j<number_of_feature_vectors_in_class[i]; j++)
            for(int k=0; k<dimension_of_each_feature_vector; k++)
                if(C[i][j][k]<smallest_range_vector_for_class[i][k])
                    smallest_range_vector_for_class[i][k]=C[i][j][k];

//Debug info only
//for(int i=0;i<number_of_classes;i++)
//  for(int k=0;k<dimension_of_each_feature_vector;k++)
//          printf("\nclass %d smallest component %d is %.3f",i,k,smallest_range_vector_for_class[i][k]);
    double** largest_range_vector_for_class=new double*[number_of_classes];
    for(int i=0; i<number_of_classes; i++)
        largest_range_vector_for_class[i]=new double[dimension_of_each_feature_vector];
    for(int i=0; i<number_of_classes; i++)
        for(int k=0; k<dimension_of_each_feature_vector; k++)
            largest_range_vector_for_class[i][k]=C[i][0][k];
    for(int i=0; i<number_of_classes; i++)
        for(int j=1; j<number_of_feature_vectors_in_class[i]; j++)
            for(int k=0; k<dimension_of_each_feature_vector; k++)
                if(C[i][j][k]>largest_range_vector_for_class[i][k])
                    largest_range_vector_for_class[i][k]=C[i][j][k];

//Debug info only
//for(int i=0;i<number_of_classes;i++)
//  for(int k=0;k<dimension_of_each_feature_vector;k++)
//          printf("\nclass %d largest component %d is %.3f",i,k,largest_range_vector_for_class[i][k]);
    int R=0;
    int F=0;
    for(int ia=0; ia<number_of_classes; ia++)
        for(int ib=0; ib<number_of_classes; ib++)
            for(int j=0; j<number_of_feature_vectors_in_class[ib]; j++)
                for(int k=0; k<dimension_of_each_feature_vector; k++)
                {
                    if(ib!=ia)
                    {
                        if((C[ib][j][k]>smallest_range_vector_for_class[ia][k])&&(C[ib][j][k]<largest_range_vector_for_class[ia][k]))
                            R++;
                        F++;
                    }
                }
    double beta=((double)(R))/((double)(F));
    printf("\nBETA: %.3f",beta);
    printf("\nP=(G1,G2)=(%.3f,%.3f)",alpha-beta,alpha+beta-1);
    printf("\nDistance from P to (1,0): %.3f",sqrt(pow((alpha-beta)-1,2)+pow(alpha+beta-1,2)));
    printf("\n\n");
}
/////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////
double mean_similarities(double** v,int n, int t)
{
    double largest;
    double smallest;
    double* s=new double[t];
    for(int i=0; i<t; i++)
    {
        smallest=1;
        largest=0;
        for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
        {
            if(v[j][i]>largest)
                largest=v[j][i];
            if(v[j][i]<smallest)
                smallest=v[j][i];
        }
        s[i]=1-(largest-smallest);
    }
    double m=0;
    for(int i=0; i<t; i++)
        m+=s[i];
    m/=((double)(t));
    return(m);
}
```

PS: to find the best classifier result, I need to change the size of the file size (amount of information for each file) to increasingly larger values. At first with 512 points, but I double this value with each execution until I reach 8192, but when I try with 16384 the code crashes. I am working with 10780 files where each one has the same dimension and I increase it as I check the result.

Comment: Unrelated: In the real world [Three Star Programmers](https://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer) should be avoided.

Comment: @user4581301 what does this have to do with three star programming, I do not see any dynamic memory allocation or the such??

Comment: @YunfeiChen scroll down to the `Do NOT change anything BELOW this line !!!!!` The next line is a 3D Array done the most painful way possible. In this case it might be justified, though, because it keeps the size of the memory blocks managable. Leaks like a sieve, though

Comment: @user4581301 a couple of things I noticed: First of all it looks like he has an extra else statement... Also it looks like he is writing to the file tens of thousands of times, closing and opening, just curious how expensive is his program exactly, it looks like it would crash a system?? Or take a while....

Comment: @user4581301 Wow that looks ugly, how do you even delete that monsterisity?? After you are done with it of course...

Comment: @user4581301 1, 2, 3, 4,5 for loops for intializing an array, wow this guy should take a course on algoritms and data structures....

Comment: In the middle of the code, there is a comment with "DO NOT change anything below this line !!!!!" This is from the developer of the algorithm, but if you have any tips that can better handle the following steps in the code without changing the result, it will also help

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have a lot of problems below:

```
double** largest_range_vector_for_class=new double*[number_of_classes];
    for(int i=0; i<number_of_classes; i++)
        largest_range_vector_for_class[i]=new double[dimension_of_each_feature_vector];
    for(int i=0; i<number_of_classes; i++)
        for(int k=0; k<dimension_of_each_feature_vector; k++)
            largest_range_vector_for_class[i][k]=C[i][0][k];
    for(int i=0; i<number_of_classes; i++)
        for(int j=1; j<number_of_feature_vectors_in_class[i]; j++)
            for(int k=0; k<dimension_of_each_feature_vector; k++)
                if(C[i][j][k]>largest_range_vector_for_class[i][k])
                    largest_range_vector_for_class[i][k]=C[i][j][k];
```

I can't even read that, but I do get the gist of it, basically you created a dynamic array, a 3D dynamic array, but nowhere in your program did you free the memory that was used by the 3D array, it looks very leaky, I cannot delete for you because I have trouble reading that monstersity....